# Is it possible to prevent send custom id by rules in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Is there any way to prevent user send custom id for newly created document?
For example

This operation create's new document with id "8pqLuAc6BXCVRF7SB6xT"

```
db.collection("users").add({foo : 1})
```

And in my application i always want to have id generate by firebase sdk not by user

because as we know user can hack app and trigger operation like this

```
db.collection("users").doc('CUSTOM_ID').set({foo : 1})
```

After this operation id will be "CUSTOM_ID" instead generated by SDK like '8pqLuAc6BXCVRF7SB6xT'

So question is how to write rule to ensure me that id is generated from sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update following your clarification:

It is not possible with Security Rules to avoid a user specifying the ID of a document when it is created.

Even if the code in your front end only uses the `add()` method, one can write his own code and use the `doc()` method to write to your DB (as soon as he gets the Firebase configuration object, which is easy).

One possibility would be to write to Firestore via a Cloud Function, but this has some drawbacks see this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c).

---

##### Original answer:

It is not crystal clear what you mean by a "custom id" but I understand that you probably want a given user to be able to create a document in the `users` collection only if this document ID is corresponding to his user uid (from the Auth service)

The following Security Rule should the trick:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: to be more cleary i have edited question